How to prove that unit operators are the only operators with zero scaling dimension in an unitary CFT?
In David Simmons-Duffin's Phys 229 notes found on author's github here pg. 147 it is said that the free boson field $\phi$ in bosonic CFT has zero dimension but it is not the unit operator. So the theory is not unitary. I don't understand how the first statement implies the 2nd i.e. the theory is non-unitary. Namely, why are unit operators the only operators in a unitary theory with zero scaling dimension? I have no idea how to show this.

The identity is the operator with no descendants whatsoever. If you create the state on the cylinder $\left | 1 \right >$ with it, then $P_\mu \left | 1 \right > = 0$. Now suppose there's some other primary state $\left | 0 \right >$ with $\Delta = 0$. We can then project $P_\mu \left | 0 \right >$ onto its conjugate to get
\begin{align}
\left < 0 \right | K_\mu P_\mu \left | 0 \right > &= \left < 0 \right | [K_\mu, P_\mu] \left | 0 \right > \\
&= \left < 0 \right | 2d D \left | 0 \right > \\
&= 0.
\end{align}
The first step used primality and the second step used the conformal algebra. Now we have built a state with zero norm. So either the theory is non-unitary, or $P_\mu \left | 0 \right >$ would've had to not exist in the first place which gets us back to $\left | 0 \right >$ being the identity.

But do the existence of null states necessarily make the theory non-unitary? I mean, we can always mod these out of the Verma module in the usual way, right... or do we usually then considering a different theory altogether?

Modding out the states is equivalent to stating that any operator with $\Delta = 0$ MUST satisfy $P_\mu O(x) = 0$, equivalent to the statement $\partial_\mu O(x) = 0$ implying that $O(x)$ does not depend on $x$ and is a $c$-number operator. Up to a normalization, it is therefore proportional to the identity operator.

Oh ok. Another last question: does existence of state of zero norm as opposed to negative norm at all indicate non unitarity of the theory?

Yes. For a probability interpretation, you need to be able to rescale the state to make the norm 1.
